# Estimate $\sum_{j=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{(j+1)(n-j+1)}$.

Tags: summation, asymptotics

Estimate,
or give an exact formula for
$g(n)
=\sum_{j=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{(j+1)(n-j+1)}
$.

This comes from my answer here:
[Cauchy product of $\sum\limits_n^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ with itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091200/cauchy-product-of-sum-limits-n-infty-frac1n-with-itself/2091227#2091227)

Numerical experimentation
suggests that
$g(n)$
is decreasing and
is about
$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}-1}$,
so it seems that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}g(n)
$
exists
and might be $1$.

(I wouldn't be surprised
if this has already been answered.)

Comment: *Hint.* What is $\frac{1}{j+1}+\frac{1}{n-j+1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{(j+1)(n-j+1)}\right)&=\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{j=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{j+1}+\frac{1}{n-j+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2}{n+2}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{1}{j+1}\\\\
&=\frac{2}{n+2}H_{n+1}
\end{align}$$

Hence, as $n\to \infty$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{(j+1)(n-j+1)}\right)&=\frac{2\log(n+1)}{n+2}+\frac{2\gamma}{n+2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\log(n)}{n}+\frac{2\gamma}{n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I should have seen this. Oy.

Comment: First, Happy New Year Marty!  Second, I cannot begin to tell you the number of times that I've missed what later appeared to be the so-called obvious.  Anyway, pleased I was able to help.  -Mark